# como transformar uma variável factor em numérico no R?

Tags: r

Bom dia estou a importar uma base de dados do formato txt e os valores vem em fator mas quero em numeric. Como que faço?

Comment: Se isto está ocorrendo, deve ter algum caractere não-numérico na coluna. Se for algum que indique valor missing, use o argumento `na.strings`. É melhor tentar resolver o problema nos dados antes de fazer essa conversão.

Comment: Bom dia Molx, muito obrigado pela resposta. Após aplicar a sua sugestão passei a ter a variável como caracter. Manda-me seu mail vou mardar a base de dados. Abraços

Answer (score -2):

Cara, tenta o seguinte:

```
variavel <- data.frame(nome_da_base, stringsAsFactors = F)
```